# unable to authenticate jira API with angular JS(cookie based authentication)

Tags: angularjs, cookies, jira-rest-api

i just tried the jira authentication API for cookies in postman and it worked perfectly fine. i got the cookie with the session ID which i used in other API calls.
But when i tried the exact same POST call in angularjs,it didn't work at all.

code for angular js $http call

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://gsd.company.com/jira/rest/auth/1/session",
    data:JSON.stringify({"username": "user@company.com", "password": "passwordrandom"}),
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response){

    console.log(response);

},function errorCallback(response){

    console.log("err");
    console.log(response);

});
```

and i get the following error on the console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://gsd.company.com/jira/rest/auth/1/session. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

I've tried nearly every solution out there like setting access headers in the client call but nothing works. Thanks in advance?

Answer (score -1):

it should simply be

```
data:{""username": "user@company.com", "password": "passwordrandom"}
```